# Grab element from json dump

Tags: python, json

I'm using the following python code to connect to a jsonrpc server and nick some song information. However, I can't work out how to get the current title in to a variable to print elsewhere. Here is the code:

```
TracksInfo = []
for song in playingSongs:
    data = { "id":1,
            "method":"slim.request",
            "params":[ "", 
                        ["songinfo",0,100, "track_id:%s" % song, "tags:GPASIediqtymkovrfijnCYXRTIuwxN"]
              ]
        }
    params = json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    conn.request("POST", "/jsonrpc.js", params)
    httpResponse = conn.getresponse()
    data = httpResponse.read()
    responce = json.loads(data)
    print json.dumps(responce, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    TrackInfo = responce['result']["songinfo_loop"][0]
    TracksInfo.append(TrackInfo)
```

This brings me back the data in json format and the print json.dump brings back:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/pithon $ sudo python tom3.py 
{
    "id": 1, 
    "method": "slim.request", 
    "params": [
        "", 
        [
            "songinfo", 
            "0", 
            100, 
            "track_id:-140501481178464", 
            "tags:GPASIediqtymkovrfijnCYXRTIuwxN"
        ]
    ], 
    "result": {
        "songinfo_loop": [
            {
                "id": "-140501481178464"
            }, 
            {
                "title": "Witchcraft"
            }, 
            {
                "artist": "Pendulum"
            }, 
            {
                "duration": "253"
            }, 
            {
                "tracknum": "1"
            }, 
            {
                "type": "Ogg Vorbis (Spotify)"
            }, 
            {
                "bitrate": "320k VBR"
            }, 
            {
                "coverart": "0"
            }, 
            {
                "url": "spotify:track:2A7ZZ1tjaluKYMlT3ItSfN"
            }, 
            {
                "remote": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What i'm trying to get is result.songinfoloop.title (but I tried that!)

Comment: Your structure makes no sense. Why is `songinfoloop` a list of dictionaries, each with one element? It should be just `'songinfoloop': {'id': 'xxx, 'title': 'yyy',... }` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `songinfo_loop` structure is.. peculiar. It is a list of dictionaries each with *just one key*.

Loop through it until you have one with a title:

```
TrackInfo = next(d['title'] for d in responce['result']["songinfo_loop"] if 'title' in d)
TracksInfo.append(TrackInfo)
```

A better option would be to 'collapse' all those dictionaries into one:

```
songinfo = reduce(lambda d, p: d.update(p) or d, 
                  responce['result']["songinfo_loop"], {})
TracksInfo.append(songinfo['title'])
```

Answer (score 0):

songinfo_loop is a list not a dict.  That means you need to call it by position, or loop through it and find the dict with a key value of "title"

positional:

`responce["result"]["songinfo_loop"][1]["title"]`

loop:

```
for info in responce["result"]["songinfo_loop"]:
    if "title" in info.keys():
        print info["title"]
        break
else:
    print "no song title found"
```

Really, it seems like you would want to have the songinfo_loop be a dict, not a list.  But if you need to leave it as a list, this is how you would pull the title.

Answer (score -1):

The result is really a standard python dict, so you can use

```
responce["result"]["songinfoloop"]["title"]
```

which should work

Comment: No it is not. It is a list of dictionaries.